# Firebase Admin SDK: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-admin

Currently I'm trying to verify a Firebase IdToken within a JUnit Test via the Firebase Admin SDK. Everytime I insert a valid token, I get the following stacktrace:

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: Error while verifying signature.
at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FirebaseTokenVerifier.verifyTokenAndSignature(FirebaseTokenVerifier.java:167)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$4.execute(FirebaseAuth.java:462)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$4.execute(FirebaseAuth.java:449)
at com.google.firebase.internal.CallableOperation.call(CallableOperation.java:36)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(FirebaseAuth.java:413)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(FirebaseAuth.java:387)
at my.package.FirebaseJwtTest.test(FirebaseJwtTest.java:32)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1974)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:345)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:339)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.checkServerCerts(ClientHandshaker.java:1968)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1777)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:264)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1098)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processRecord(Handshaker.java:1026)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.processInputRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1137)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1074)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1402)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1429)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:163)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:104)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.refresh(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:172)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.getPublicKeys(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:141)
at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FirebaseTokenVerifier.verifySignature(FirebaseTokenVerifier.java:193)
at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FirebaseTokenVerifier.verifyTokenAndSignature(FirebaseTokenVerifier.java:161)
... 30 moreCaused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:343)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:226)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:133)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.checkServerCerts(ClientHandshaker.java:1947)
... 49 moreCaused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
... 55 more
```

This is the unit test:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class FirebaseJwtTest {

  private static final String TOKEN = "someValidToken";

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    try (final FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(
     "src/main/resources/my_service_account.json")) {

    final FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)).setProjectId("my-project-id")
        .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(TOKEN);
  }
}
```

And the used version of Firebase Admin SDK:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've set up the Firebase service account as it is described in the documentation and followed the instructions for token verification.
My Notebook is not behind any Proxy or in any company network.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Try the steps in https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target

Comment: @Hiranya-Jayathilaka: Thanks for that tip, now it works. I would answer the question and mention that you posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target) @hiranya-jayathilaka posted in the comments contained the solution for the problem. Thanks for again.

I followed these steps to get the test above to work:

1. Getting the sources for InstallCert.java from [here](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target)
2. Create Java File and compile it (in my case I had to make the inner class `SavingTrustManager` public)
3. Running `sudo java InstallCert www.googleapis.com`
4. When prompted for the found certificates, I choosed `CN=*.googleapis.com, O=Google LLC, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US`
5. Made a backup of the original `cacerts`, copied the created `jssecacerts` into the cacerts directory and renamed it to `cacerts`